# issue with SWIG directors not working as expected

Tags: python, inheritance, swig

I am using SWIG to link between my CPP API and Python API

I created a simple callback class in my .i file and I am inheriting from it in my .py file,
but when I pass the python created class as a pointer the overridden function is not getting called,
here is the code:

```
//example.i


%module(directors="1") example

%inline %{
class CBack {
    public:
        virtual int operator()(int x, int y) const {
            return x+y;
        }
        virtual int handle(int x, int y)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        virtual ~CBack() {}
    };

    int callF(CBack* f, int xv, int yv)
    {
        return f->handle(xv, yv);
    }
%}

%feature("director") CBack;
```

```
//example.py


class Mul(example.CBack):

    @override
    def handle(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
        return x * y

print(example.callF(Mul(), 3, 7)) //print -1 but should print 21

print(str(Mul().handle(3,7))) // print 21
```

I attached the code that shows what I tried,
I expect the dispatched call to be invoked

Comment: Please don’t edit the question with the solution. Instead, upvote/accept the answer that best answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%feature("director") CBack;` must be declared before the code is processed.  Move it earlier in the code:

```cpp
// example.i
%module(directors="1") example
%feature("director") CBack;

%inline %{
class CBack {
    public:
        virtual int operator()(int x, int y) const {
            return x+y;
        }
        virtual int handle(int x, int y)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        virtual ~CBack() {}
    };

    int callF(CBack* f, int xv, int yv)
    {
        return f->handle(xv, yv);
    }
%}
```

```
# test.py
import example

class Mul(example.CBack):
    def handle(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
        return x * y

print(example.callF(Mul(), 3, 7))
print(str(Mul().handle(3,7)))
```

Output:

```
21
21
```

Comment: You are a true life saver!